# Where is an appropriate place to ask about best practices for WordPress coding?

Tags: discussion

If i want to ask a question about coding practices where could I ask that Obviously, it would be a bit opinion based but there would likely be some very logical answers to my questions.

Comment: if you think it is opinion based than it is hard to see how will you get a very useful answer

Comment: .... but maybe the best way is just to ask and try to be specific enough to avoid too much "opion based" answers. Worst thing that can happen is that it will be closed

Comment: I don't really but someone may  interpret it as such

Comment: Thanks Mark..   I'll try!  In meta or regular WP stack?

Comment: regular of course ;)

Comment: Okay.  Do you want to post as an answer here to close the question?

Comment: lets give smarter people a chance to answer first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discussions regarding best practices I believe are made more for a discussion format. There are [tons of blog posts](https://goo.gl/zLarXQ) which go into different depths of best practices. You're right, questions like this are too open-ended and since everyone comes from different backgrounds, each will have their own opinion. As we can see, [in the past](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/715/7355) it has not worked well. While it is a popular question is also has a bunch of answers, too many.

So, where to ask such things? If you're not too cynical you can read through the [WordPress handbook](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/) ( or more specifically for [plugin development](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/best-practices/) and [theme development](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/) ). Below is a list of open discussion sites:

- [WPSE Chat, The Loop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop). We're always here, it's an infinite loop.
- [WordPress IRC Chat](https://codex.wordpress.org/IRC) is almost always populated.
- [WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forum/wp-advanced/)
- Use social media to reach out. Most social media platforms have a few groups dedicated to WordPress.
- Reach out to a local meetup. Wordpress has [many local meetups](https://www.meetup.com/topics/wordpress/) across the world.
- [Attend a WordCamp](https://central.wordcamp.org/)

Some of the above options require more effort than others but I believe all are good resources to discuss best practices with actual people working in the field. There are probably premium help forums or 3rd party help forums that I am missing but if you really want that as an option they're not difficult to find.

Comment: Your answer makes sense and i'll check the links as resources. my question is not as the example but more towards function usage in loops or actually creating the loop